# How do I get all the <span> items under a specific section id? (JSoup)

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm trying to get all the  items with class "frame-title" that are underneath the "favorites" section id. Very very new to web crawls, so I'm sure it's simple.

**Html:**

```
<section id="favourites" class="section">
 <h2 class="section-heading">Favorite films</h2>
    <div>
     <a href="/film/wings-of-desire/" class="frame has-menu" data-original-title="Wings of Desire (1987)"><span class="frame-title">Wings of Desire (1987)</span>
```

I want to retrieve the "frame-title" part. So the title of the film.

**This is what I've tried:**

```
for (int x = 0; x<users.size();x++)
        {
           String url2 = "https://letterboxd.com" + users.get(x);
           Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2).get();
           Elements films = doc.select("a:has(frame-title)");;
           
              for (Element film:films){
           String temp = films.attr("href").toString();
           films1.add(temp);
           System.out.println(temp);    
         }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String url = "https://letterboxd.com/saka1029/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements films = doc.select("section#favourites span.frame-title");
for (Element film : films) {
    System.out.println(film);
}
```

output:

```
<span class="frame-title">Ghost in the Shell</span>
```

It's my favorite. :)

Comment: Oh that works! Thanks! Just one thing, how could I isolate just the title? Without any of the html around it. I want to add each movie title to an arraylist.

Comment: You can get the title by `film.text()`.